# React Navigation wrap tab navigator with a HOC

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I'm basically trying to wrap the entire navigator in let's say redux (but it isn't redux) like so:

```
<HOC1>
    <HOC2>
        <HOC3>
            <HOC4>
                <TabNavigator />
            </HOC4>
        </HOC3>
    </HOC2>
</HOC1>
```

The thing is, `HOC3` and `HOC4` look something like this:

```
const HOC3 = () = {
    if(someCondition){
        return {this.props.children}
    }
    return <Text>Doing some work!</Text>
}
```

And these components basically wait for some conditions, and then return children. Instead of `<Text>`, I'd be showing a loading spinner eg.

Since the app has an authentication flow, I'll start with `createSwitchNavigator` that'll switch between registration (or `createStackNavigator`) and the app itself (or `createBottomTabNavigator`).

I wanna wrap the tabs, so I' was trying to do something like:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Page1: { screen: Page1 },
    Page2: { screen: Page2 },
})

class AppNavigator extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HOC1>
                <HOC2>
                    <HOC3>
                        <HOC4>
                            <TabNavigator />
                        </HOC4>
                    </HOC3>
                </HOC2>
            </HOC1>
        )
    }
}

export default AppNavigator
```

However, no matter what I do, it doesn't work like this. According to their docs, I'm supposed to define a `static router` and pass `this.props.navigation` to the navigator, if I wanted to do something like this, and even if I do that, it doesn't work. I don't want to show this navigation until certain conditions are met, and I don't want the navigation to handle these conditions. So basically: how do I wrap a tab navigator that I pass to a switch navigator?

Comment: I have the same requirement, did you get this to work?

Comment: @dentemm not really, after days of trying this out, I ended up using https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router instead. It works like a charm, especially if you're already used to React Router as such. I haven't posted it as an answer here, considering it's a solution to the approach, not the specific problem, but I just might now!

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply! After giving it some thought I realised that I didn't really need to wrap the TabNavigator, but the TabBar component. So I created a custom TabBar which I was able to wrap without issues.

Comment: @dentemm if you cracked a way to control render of the navigation itself with a HOC, maybe post a working code example? That would be cool. Can you do something like `if(someCondition) { return <LoadingSpinner /> } else { return <TabBar /> }`? My specific use case needed to block render of the navigation, thus blocking any `componentDidMount` or `constructor` calls I have in the pages themselves

Answer (score 0):

So while this doesn't solve the specific problem of using React Navigation and HOCs, it does solve the idea of using any navigation/router with any HOCs you like, especially if you're used to how React handles routing:

[React Router link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)

It works exactly like React, so you can wrap your router in anything you like:

```
<HOC>
    <HOC2>
        <HOC3>
            <HOC4>
                <NativeRouter>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
                    <Route about="/about" component={About}>
                </NativeRouter>
            </HOC4>
        <HOC3>
    <HOC2>
<HOC1>
```

In this specific instance, if you got weird race conditions or something along the lines, the router will not be rendered/use-able until the HOCs are resolved. Using this approach, however, **DOES NOT let you pass stuff to routes as props**. So if you have a HOC that's supposed to resolve something, and pass that something to router/routes, you should use Redux or something similar.